# PHP Class Not Loading

Tags: php, wordpress, classloader

I'm using WordPress and I'm trying to write a plugin that uses a file from another plugin. The URL to get the file is correct. I'm able to include the file when I'm calling a static function from the class, it is saying that the class is not loading.

```
//loading the file
$url=plugins_url().'/nextgen-gallery/admin/functions.php';
include $url;
```

The filename is `functions`.php and in it is a class defined `nggAdmin`

However, when i call the `function nggAdmin::create_gallery();,` i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'nggAdmin' not found in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Product/addProductForm.php on line 27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plugins_url()` gives you the url, e.g. `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-plugins/`, not the server path - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` instead - http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: yes, plugins_url() give the plugin directory, thats y i'm contacting plugins_url().'/nextgen-gallery/admin/functions.php'

Comment: but that's not how `include` works - it needs the server path, e.g. `/var/www/wordpress/wp-plugins/my-plugin.php`, not the URL `http://example.com/wp-plugins/my-plugin.php`